# Hacer que un useState se ejecute cada cierto tiempo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Como va?
Tengo un token que dura 20 minutos cada vez que pasa del login y este se usa en varios componentes para mostrar ciertos datos, el problema es que al pasar los 20 minutos de sesión empiezan a fallar todos las consultas de axios.

Mi consulta es: Hay alguna manera de hacer un useEffect donde cada x tiempo consulte si ese token es valido? Con el fin de que, al no ser valido, este muestre un cartel de error y lo mande de nuevo a la pantalla login.

Dejo mi consulta de axios

```
 useEffect(() => {
        instance.get(`api/personas/${idUsuario}`)
        .then(res => setPersona(res.data)
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
         window.location.href = "/";
        });  
      }, [])
```

No se en que parte meterle un timer o cual seria una buena manera de hacer un temporizador.

Comment: Buenas. Yo evitaría usar intervalos o timeouts para llamadas a la api. Sería mejor controlar el error que te devuelve el api y si es por el token caducado, redireccionar al login. Para no tener que hacerlo en todas las llamadas, yo haría una función que se encargue de llamar a la api y controle los errores.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla que se me ocurre de hacer esto es utilizando "setInterval".

Por ejemplo, en este caso para ejecutar la función por ejemplo cada 5 segundos, que serian 5000 milisegundos tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    instance.get(`api/personas/${idUsuario}`)
    .then(res => setPersona(res.data))
    .catch(function (error) {
      window.location.href = "/";
    });
  }, 5000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };
}, []);
```

Es importante usar el "clearInterval" en el return de tu useEffect para evitar fugas de memoria en tu aplicación.